# How to make recording audio react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a project, just user tap in the button and it started recording. If user haven't speak, it stops, and if user tap at the same button, record stopped. Now it can storage in local path, but i hope in the futere i will requests this files in the server
The code:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Pressable } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { useAuth } from '../AuthContext'
import { COLORS } from '../assets/colors/colors';
import Train_word from '../assets/images/Train_word.svg'
import Train_word_2 from '../assets/images/Train_word_2.svg'


const Train = () => {
  const [user] = useAuth()
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <Image
                source={require('../assets/images/Logo_small.png')}
                style={styles.logo_s}
                resizeMode='contain'/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.main_cont}>
            <Train_word marginBottom={34}/>
            <Train_word_2 marginBottom={55}/>
            <Pressable marginBottom={180}>
                <Image
                    source={require('../assets/images/Start_img.png')}
                    style={styles.start_img}>
                </Image>
            </Pressable>
            <Pressable style={styles.result}>
                <Text style={styles.text_result}>Получить результат</Text>
            </Pressable>
        </View>
        <Image
        source={require('../assets/images/bottom_menu.png')}
        style={styles.img_bg}/>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Train

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(243, 239, 239, 1)",
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    img_bg: {
        width: 412,
        height: 80,
    },
    
    logo_s: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        left: 150,
        top: -130,
    },

    header: {
        backgroundColor: 'transeparent',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems:'center',
        height: 100,
        paddingTop: 180,
        paddingRight: 35
    },

    main_cont: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        top: -90,
        flex: 1,
    },

    start_img: {
        width: 286,
        height: 286,
    },

    result: {
        backgroundColor: 'transeparent',
        width: 178,
        height: 25,
        alignItems: "center",
        left: -63,
        
    },
  
    text_result: {
        fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Italic',
        color: COLORS.text,
        fontSize: 16,
        textDecorationLine: 'underline'
    }
})
```

Thanks for everyone, i'm beginner in react native